Filament 3.x bulkaction url closure problem
I have a table full of records of ModelA.
In this table I am trying to make a bulkaction.
This bulkaction should redirect to a route provided in the web.php in a new tab.
However there are some conditions.
First and foremost I need to have actual records selected, the rest don't really matter for the issue.
            BulkAction::make('generate_report')
            ->label('Blabla name and stuff')
            ->requiresConfirmation()
            //->url('urlthatworks') //this works 100% as we want.
            ->url(function ($records) {
                $route = '';
                if ($records) {
                    $route = route('name_in_webphp', ['param1' => 'somevalue', 'param2' => 'someothervalue'])
                    //dd($route); //this dd gets hit when uncommented and print the url that works 100% if we hardcode it like above.
                }
                return $route;
            })
            ->openUrlInNewTab()
            ->icon('heroicon-o-eye'),

This is the bulkaction we wish to use, however it doesnt do anything when we select a row and press the bulkactionbutton.
For a complete picture the web.php has the route defined:
Route::get('route/{param1}/{param2}', [Destination::class, 'destinationfunction'])->name('name_in_webphp');

And the Destination class has this destinationfunction function which just has a dd to print param1 and param2.
My question is as follows:
Why doesnt the closure redirects us to the new tab and route while a hardcoded value of the route works just fine?
Did I do something wrong or is there an issue in filament?
Is there some workaround?

The url function is calculated only when the component is rendered for the first time.
It creates an a element only if the parameter you pass in is not null and not empty.
Therefore, what you are trying to achieve is currently not possible. When you click the button, the href won't be updated to the route you are returning (since is a button element). The reason is that $records is always null when the url function is calculated. $records is a Collection when you select records and click on the bulk action, but since the url fn is only calculated the first time the component loads, $records is null.
Note also that the openUrlInNewTab won't work in this case, since you are rendering a button, not an a.
What could be an option?

Using the action fn instead of the url function:

->action(function (Collection $records, \Livewire\Component $livewire): void {
    $livewire->redirectRoute(name: 'name', parameters: []);
})

What problems it has?

You cannot open the url in a new tab (related question).

Docs:

Injecting the current Livewire component instance


The action fn is currently the workaround i am using with a redirectto. In the target controller I am building a pdf. And found that streaming the pdf back with my pdf lib uses the same tab. However the download (which is actually what i wanted anyway) does open a new tab.
